# How to correctly format paths in sql statements (Exception when running Restore from C# .net)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

When I do run this SqlCommand from .net C#:

```
RESTORE DATABASE dba
FROM DISK="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.INSTANZ_A\MSSQL\Backup\dba.bak",
WITH MOVE "dba_Data" TO "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.INSTANZ_A\MSSQL\DATA\dba.mdf",
MOVE "dba_Log" TO "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.INSTANZ_A\MSSQL\DATA\dba_Log.ldf";
```

I get this exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.INSTANZ_A\MSSQL\Backup\dba.bak'.
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

There's a semicolon at the end, this is the form this statement is expected to be, I tried different styles of formatting the paths, once with " and with ' around them also.

Please help.

Comment: How do you write the command text in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma before `WITH MOVE` it is not required

```sql
RESTORE DATABASE dba
FROM DISK='C:\Program Files\..Backup\dba.bak' --here
WITH MOVE 'dba_Data' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.INSTANZ_A\MSSQL\DATA\dba.mdf',
MOVE 'dba_Log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.INSTANZ_A\MSSQL\DATA\dba_Log.ldf';
```

Also I prefer to use single quotes for string literals in sql server instead of double quotes

Comment: @Juan - Am not sure exactly where but in some setting sql server accepts double quotes for strings thats why I placed that comment..

Comment: I think you might be right. Now that I think about it, I think there was a setting or something...